# Select all options in optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select` element with grouped `option`s. I need to select (or deselect) all `option`s in an `optgroup` when an `option` is clicked.  I also need to be able to have multiple `optgroup`s being selected at once.

The way I wish it to work is this:

- If nothing is selected, I want to click one option and get all of the options in the same optgroup selected.
- If one or more optgroups are already selected, I want to click one option in another optgroup and have all those options selected instead.
- If one or more optgroups are already selected, I want to be able to Ctrl-click an option  in a non-selected optgroup and have all of the options in that optgroup selected too.
- If one or more optgroups are already selected, I want to be able to Ctrl-click an option in a selected optgroup and have all the options in that group deselected.

Looking at other answers on Stack Overflow I created the following:

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="10">
    <optgroup label="Queen">
        <option value="Mercury">Freddie</option>
        <option value="May">Brian</option>
        <option value="Taylor">Roger</option>
        <option value="Deacon">John</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Pink Floyd">
        <option value="Waters">Roger</option>
        <option value="Gilmour">David</option>    
        <option value="Mason">Nick</option>                
        <option value="Wright">Richard</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('select').click(selectSiblings);
function selectSiblings(ev) {
    var clickedOption = $(ev.target);
    var siblings = clickedOption.siblings();
    if (clickedOption.is(":selected")) {
        siblings.attr("selected", "selected");
    } else {
        siblings.removeAttr("selected");
    }
}​
```

I made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mflodin/Ndkct/
(Sadly jsFiddle doesn't seem to support IE8 any more.)

This works as expected in Firefox (16.0), but in IE8 it doesn't work at all. From other answers I have found out that IE8 can't handle the `click` event on `optgroup` or `option`, which is the reason I bind it to the `select` and then use `$(ev.target)`. But in IE8 the `$(ev.target)` still points to the entire `select` and not to the `option` that was clicked. How can I find out which `option` (or containing `optgroup`) that was clicked and whether it was selected or deselected?

Another unexpected behaviour, but minor in comparison, is that in Chrome (20.0) the deselect doesn't happen until the mouse leaves the `select`. Does anybody know a workaround for this?
​

Answer (score 3):

not an answer to the specific question of select option cross browser issues, I think that's been answered already, but a solution to the problem of selecting the data and passing it back to the server would be to change your mark up to something which better suits multi selection

if you use checkboxes instead, you can put them in a list and add enhanching js to select all and deselect all

http://jsfiddle.net/Ndkct/43/

```
<dl>
<dt>Queen</dt>
<dd>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input id="Mercury" name="bandmembers" value="Mercury" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="Mercury">Freddie</label>
        </li>    
        <li>
            <input id="May" name="bandmembers" value="May" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="May">Brian</label>
        </li>    
        <li>
            <input id="Taylor" name="bandmembers" value="Taylor" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="Taylor">Roger</label>
        </li>    
        <li>
            <input id="Deacon" name="bandmembers" value="Deacon" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="Deacon">John</label>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</dd>
<dt>Pink Floyd</dt> ...
```

The js is now simple enough

```
$("dt")
    .css("cursor","pointer")
    .click(function(){
        var $el = $(this).next();
        var $checks = $el.find(":checkbox");
        if($checks.is(":not(:checked)")){
           $checks.attr("checked",true); 
        }else{
           $checks.attr("checked",false); 
        }
    });
```

(this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ndkct/44/ adds a parent checkbox to make it more usable)

Comment: Nice alternative solution! It might even be clearer for the user.

Comment: ta, I think so too. Listboxes and that whole left shift/control button multi select thing is just not user friendly either. You have the advantage of a hierarchy to select many items quickly here, and just looking at it tells you what's happening

Answer (score 2):

Since Internet Explorer as of version 10 still does not support any useful events on `optgroup` or `option`, any cross-browser solution to this issue can't depend on direct events from those elements.

*Note:* MSDN documentation claims that `optgroup` supports `click` events, but as of IE 10 that still does not seem to be a reality: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535876(v=vs.85).aspx

I tested the following in Chrome 27, Firefox 20, Safari 6, IE 9, and IE 10 (I don't have access to IE 8 currently).

Here's an example you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/potatosalad/Ndkct/38/

```js
// Detect toggle key (toggle selection)
$('select')
    .on('mousedown', function(event) {
        // toggleKey = Command for Mac OS X; Control for others
        var toggleKey = (!event.metaKey && event.ctrlKey && !(/Mac OS/.test(navigator.userAgent))) ? event.ctrlKey : event.metaKey;
        if (toggleKey === true) {
            $(this).data('toggleKey', true);
        }
        $(this).data('_mousedown', true);
    })
    .on('mouseup', function() {
        $(this).data('_mousedown', null);
    });
// Chrome fix for mouseup outside select
$(document).on('mouseup', ':not(select)', function() {
    var $select = $('select');
    if ($select.data('_mousedown') === true) {
        $select.data('_mousedown', null);
        $select.trigger('change');
    }
});

$('select')
    .on('focus',  storeState)
    .on('change', changeState);

function storeState() {
    $(this).data('previousGroup', $('option:selected', this).closest('optgroup'));
    $(this).data('previousVal',   $(this).val());
};

function changeState() {
    var select = this,
        args   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    var previousGroup = $(select).data('previousGroup'),
        previousVal   = $(select).data('previousVal');
    var currentGroup  = null,
        currentVal    = $(select).val();

    var selected = $('option:selected', select),
        groups   = selected.closest('optgroup');

    console.log("[change] %o -> %o", previousVal, currentVal);

    if ((previousVal === currentVal) && (groups && groups.length == 1)) {
        // selected options have not changed
        // AND
        // only 1 optgroup is selected
        // -> do nothing
    } else if (currentVal === null || currentVal.length === 0) {
        // zero options selected
        // -> store state and do nothing
        storeState.apply(select, args);
    } else { // a select/deselect change has occurred
        if ($(select).data('toggleKey') === true
            && (previousVal !== null && previousGroup !== null && groups !== null)
            && (previousVal.length > currentVal.length)
            && (previousGroup.length === groups.length)
            && (previousGroup.get(0) === groups.get(0))) {
            // options within the same optgroup have been deselected
            // -> deselect all and store state
            $(select).val(null);
            storeState.apply(select, args);
        } else if (currentVal.length === 1) {
            // single option selected
            // -> use groups
            currentGroup = groups;
        } else if (groups.length === 1) {
            // multiple options selected within same optgroup
            // -> use groups
            currentGroup = groups;
        } else {
            // multiple options selected spanning multiple optgroups
            // -> use last optgroup
            currentGroup = groups.last();
        }
    }

    $(select).data('toggleKey', null);

    if (currentGroup !== null) {
        $('optgroup', select).not(currentGroup).children(':selected').attr('selected', false);
        $(currentGroup).children(':not(:selected)').attr('selected', true);
        storeState.apply(select, args);
    }
};
```

It works by storing the previously selected group and options on the `select` element and determining which `optgroup` should be selected (or deselected).

Some behaviors can be changed based on the developers needs.  For example in the case of selecting multiple `options` that span multiple `optgroups` (by clicking and dragging down as seen in screenshot):

[image: multiple options selected spanning multiple optgroups]

The default conflict resolution for this case is to always use the last `optgroup`, but could be changed to always use the first one, or the `optgroup` with the largest number of already selected options.

Comment: This works great for selecting a single optgroup, but not multiple ones. I'll update my question to make it clearer what I need. It may be simple to modify your code for what I need, but unfortunately I do not have the time to look into it now. Still, I'll award you a +1 for the work so far and for the info regarding IE compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

this fix the problem, you only need to add this code after init chosen.

```
$( '.chzn-results .group-result' ).each( function () {
    var self      = $( this )
        , options = $( '~li', self )
        , next    = options.filter( '.group-result' ).get( 0 )
    ;
    self.data( 'chzn-options', options.slice( 0, options.index( next ) ) );
} )
.click( function () { 
    $( this ).data( 'chzn-options' ).mouseup()
 } )
.hover( function () { 
    $( this ).data( 'chzn-options' ).addClass( 'highlighted' );
 }, function () { 
    $( this ).data( 'chzn-options' ).removeClass( 'highlighted' );
 } )
.css( { cursor: 'pointer' } )
```

Thanks to  adriengibrat that posted this fix on github:

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/323

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').click(function(tar) {
        var justClickValue = tar.target.value;

        var selectedGroup = $('option[value="'+justClickValue+'"]').parent();

        if (selectedGroup.hasClass("allSelected")) {
            selectedGroup.removeClass("allSelected");
            $("option").each(function() {
                $(this).removeAttr("selected");
            });
        } else {
            $(".allSelected").removeClass("allSelected");
            selectedGroup.addClass("allSelected");
            $(".allSelected option").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your problem select/deselect all option.
you can try following code , may be help you.

code:

javascript code:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">
```

```
       $(function(){

                $('#allcheck').click(function(){
                var chk=$('#select_option >optgroup > option');
                chk.each(function(){
                  $(this).attr('selected','selected');
            });
   });  
$('#alluncheck').click(function(){

              var chk=$('#select_option >optgroup > option');
              chk.each(function(){
              $(this).removeAttr('selected');
          });
     });});
```

HtML CODE:

```
       <select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="select_option" name="option_value[]">
          <optgroup label="Queen">
            <option value="Mercury">Freddie</option>
            <option value="May">Brian</option>
            <option value="Taylor">Roger</option>
            <option value="Deacon">John</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Pink Floyd">
            <option value="Waters">Roger</option>
            <option value="Gilmour">David</option>    
            <option value="Mason">Nick</option>                
            <option value="Wright">Richard</option>
       </optgroup>
 </select>
<br>
       <strong>Select&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="cursor:pointer;" id="allcheck">All</a>
  &nbsp;|&nbsp;<a style="cursor:pointer;"  id="alluncheck">None</a></strong>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with what I want. I want to click an `option` not a link to select all `options`

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work

```
$("#SelectID").live("click",function() {
var elements = this.options; //or document.getElementById("SelectID").options;
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
   if(!elements[i].selected)
    elements[i].selected = true;
}
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want. This selects all `option` elements in all `optgroup`s. It should only select those that are in the same `optgroup` as the clicked `option`.

Comment: You are also missing the end parenthesis for the live function.