# How to return all option values?

Tags: jquery

I've an option structure like this:

```
<select id="select-filter-item" data-hasqtip="true" title="" aria-describedby="qtip-3">
<optgroup label="Operatori" type="providers-group">
    <option value="89" type="provider" google-sync="false">Johnny</option>
    <option value="91" type="provider" google-sync="false">Anthony</option>
</optgroup><optgroup label="Servizi" type="services-group">
    <option value="13" type="service">Hair</option>
</optgroup>
```

I want get only this value: 89 - 91 in the Operatori `optgroup` so I've tried this solution:

```
$("#select-filter-item>option").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

but doesn't return any value, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all options in optgroup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047165/select-all-options-in-optgroup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong selector to target option elements. You need to use:

```
$("#select-filter-item [type='providers-group'] option").map(function() { 
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcazk03v/)**