# HTML multi select add clickable input checkbox before the optgroup text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have implemented the following multi-select using html optgroup.

[image]

here is my code for the above implementation.

HTML

```
<select multiple="" class="form-control select-checkbox" size="20">
<optgroup label="One">
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Hippo</option>
  <option>Dinosaur</option>
  <option>Another Dog</option>
</optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Two">
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Hippo</option>
  <option>Dinosaur</option>
  <option>Another Dog</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Three">
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Hippo</option>
  <option>Dinosaur</option>
  <option>Another Dog</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.select-checkbox option::before {
  content: "\2610";
  width: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.select-checkbox option:checked::before {
  content: "\2611";
}
```

Jquery

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var originalScrollTop = $(this).parent().parent().scrollTop();
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    var self = this;
    $(this).parent().parent().focus();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).parent().parent().scrollTop(originalScrollTop);
    }, 0);
    
    return false;
});
```

I want to add a checkbox before the optgroup title as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

I added a below CSS to my exiting implementation.

```
.select-checkbox optgroup::before {
  content: "\2610";
  width: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.select-checkbox optgroup:checked::before {
  content: "\2611";
}
```

but the current UI looks like this and **I cant check and uncheck the checkbox displayed in optgroup.

**
[image]

**please help me to add editable input checkbox before the optgroup in HTML select element.**
refer fiddler here.

https://jsfiddle.net/nsandaruwa/0sphnk5z/12/

Comment: may this can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047165/select-all-options-in-optgroup

Comment: You cannot place HTML within a `option` element. What you're trying to do is not possible with a standard HTML `select` control. You'll need to use a third-party library such as [Select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68891084/6381711) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use checkbox instead of multi-select option.

The snippet below illustrates how you can achieve that;

```js
function multipleCheckboxControl(allInputId, inputIndex) {
 const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(inputIndex);
 const all = document.getElementById(allInputId);
 const notAll = [...checkboxes].filter((item) => item.getAttribute("id") !== allInputId);

 checkboxes.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("change", ({ target }) => {
   if (target.getAttribute("id") === allInputId) {
checkboxes.forEach((item) => (item.checked = target.checked));
   } else if (notAll.filter((item) => item.checked).length !== notAll.length) {
all.indeterminate = true;
   }
  });
 });
}

multipleCheckboxControl("all-b1-checkboxes", 'input[class="b1-checkbox"]');
multipleCheckboxControl("all-b2-checkboxes", 'input[class="b2-checkbox"]');
multipleCheckboxControl("all-b3-checkboxes", 'input[class="b3-checkbox"]');
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.text-bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-checkbox">
  <label class="text-bold">
    <input id="all-b1-checkboxes" class="b1-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    One
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b1-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Dog
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b1-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Cat
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b1-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Hippo
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b1-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Dinosaur
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b1-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Another Dog
  </label>
  <hr>
  <label class="text-bold">
    <input id="all-b2-checkboxes" class="b2-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Two
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b2-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Dog
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b2-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Cat
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b2-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Hippo
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b2-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Dinosaur
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b2-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Another Dog
  </label>
  <hr>
  <label class="text-bold">
    <input id="all-b3-checkboxes" class="b3-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Three
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b3-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Dog
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b3-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Cat
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b3-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Hippo
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b3-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Dinosaur
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="b3-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Another Dog
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @NirangaSandaruwan: You may want to accept as answer since it answers your questions. :-)